# Draw from the box

Tags: probability

There is a box containing $k$ numbered balls (from $1$ to $k$). We withdraw one ball with replacement $n$ times $(n\leq k)$. Compute probability that none of the balls repeated (only distinct balls) or that the $m$-th ball was taken at least once (**the $m$-th ball from was obtained at least once**).

Let's define:

$A \ - $ each one of the balls was withdrawn once

$B \ - $ the $m$-th ball was taken at least once

$|\Omega|=k^n$

$|A|=k(k-1)...(k-n+1)$

$|B|=k^n-(k-1)(k-2)...(k-n)$

but now I am a bit lost. Shall I compute it in this way:

$\mathbb P(A \cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A \cap B)=\mathbb P(B)$?

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  Since the event "ball $m$ is drawn at least once" is implied by  the event "each of the $k$ balls is drawn at least once" the union of your two events is just the event "ball $m$ is drawn at least once".  Or have I misread the events?

Comment: please note if each ball has to be withdrawn at least once, $n \ge k$. So how do you do $k-n+1$? Your calculation of $A$ and $B$ do not seem right.

Comment: @lulu I agree with you. That is the best interpretation that can be made given the badly written question. Also note it uses "at least" for ball m but does not use it for "each ball was withdrawn once" which does not make sense.

Comment: @lulu that's why I wrote that an intersection equals to A.
MathLover I've edited my post.

Comment: But...are you sure?  Perhaps event $A$ was meant to read "exactly once".  The phrasing is very strange.

Comment: Anyway, $P(B)$ is just $1-\left( \frac {k-1}k\right)^n$.  But it seems quite strange to simply ignore event $A$.  I think there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: @lulu Is the question more understandable now?

Comment: Now your edit is more confusing. What do you mean none of the balls repeat? How do you withdraw each of them exactly once unless $n = k$ or rest of them are all ball $m$?

Comment: No.  Now the only way that event $A$ is possible is if $n=k$, which was never stated.

Comment: Sorry, that's probably translating issues. "None of the balls repeated" means that if I withdraw from a set ${1,2,3,4,5}$ I can't get, for example, ${1,2,2}$.

Comment: Guys, there is "or". It's not "and".

Comment: That's how we read it.  Both as to "repeated" and "or".  The only way to draw each of balls $1$ through $k$ exactly once is if you draw exactly $k$ times (and get extremely lucky).  Thus your new event $A$ only makes sense if $k=n$.  I think this problem is quite confused.

Comment: @lulu first part: if my box is $\{{1,2,3,4,5}\}$ (so $k = 5$) and for example if $n=3$ then set $\{1,2,3\}$ satisfies this condition. second part: if $m=2$ is to appear at least once, let's consider it appears for example twice, so: $\{1,2,2,3\}$

Comment: @lulu now I can see where the confusion does come from. It's not that all balls have to be used, it's just that in A I have to draw $n$ distinct balls (in the number sense)

Comment: So you are saying that event $A$ ought to have read "no ball is drawn more than once"?   Ok.  That makes sense.  And now neither event includes the other.  I have already shown you how to compute $P(B)$, can you compute $P(A)$?

Comment: @lulu Yes! No ball is drawn more than once. I'm sorry. Are you sure these events are disjunctive? In A I can either get a set with ball $m$ or without.

Comment: @lulu Isn't $\mathbb P(A)=\frac{k(k-1)...(k-n+1)}{k^n}$ correct?

Comment: if by "disjunctive" you mean "mutually exclusive" then, No.  The events are not mutually exclusive.  For your earlier events we had one as a subevent of the other.  That is not the case with your new events.

Comment: So, now you have computed $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.  All that remains is for you to compute $P(A\cap B)$.